# CSS - ul list-style not rendered

Tags: css, html-lists

Can't figure this one out. I'm trying to set a simple list image, and it's not displayed. This happens on chrome and firefox, but in IE8 the list image is displayed perfectly.

This is the page I'm developing:
http://www.clarionproject.com/

P.S: also when I try to set: list-style:none its doesn't work. it keeps displaying the disc type.

Comment: Can you post the html you are having a problem with into your question please? Don't make people guess and search for the problem.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: There's ul, a css for list image, and it doesn't work. Should I really paste the entire html+css?

Comment: paste the relevant code and create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem if possible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the list-style to your "li"

Screenshot: https://www.box.net/shared/u1bdwuzh2fwk2pcol4x9

Comment: You're right, I have a css rule for the li... silly me. by the way, what is the formal element to apply it to: ul or li?

Comment: `list-style` is for `ul`, not `li`

Comment: maybe I was too concise, but I meant to say that it has to be declared on `ul` - it of course affects the display of `li`. see example: `ul { list-style: circle; }`

Comment: @Luca Yes you are right. I have gone through the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#list-style) now. It is recommended to give to `ul` as giving to `li` may result in unexpected results.

Comment: @MosheShaham apply to `ul`.